# Comparing Strings / using LIKE in an if statement

Tags: apex, soql, bulkification

I have an interesting issue:

1. I have a custom object record created with a String for a client Name.
2. I then have to compare that String to Account.Name.
3. If match, add it to a wrapper.
4. I use SOQL to get Accounts that have similar names, but don't know how to match them with the String values without using SOQL in a for-loop.

Here is my code:

```
list <complaint__C> tempComplaintList = new list <complaint__c>([SELECT name, ID, Complainant__c FROM complaint__C]);

//List to hold the string value of the Client Names
string[] tempNameList = new string[]{};

//once have results, populate wrapper
if(tempComplaintList.size()>0){

    for(complaint__c eachComplaint:tempComplaintList){
        wrapComplaint tempWrap = new wrapcomplaint();
        tempWrap.complaintObj = eachComplaint;
        wrapComplaintList.add(tempWrap);
        //We need to do a match, since we get only the complainant name as a string, so add wildcards so we can compare in the SOQL later

        if(eachComplaint.complainant__c !=null){ 
            tempNameList.add('%'+string.valueOf(eachComplaint.Complainant__c)+'%');
        }
    }

    //List of Clients that have similar names to the complainant strings.  LIKE in this case is both an IN: and LIKE: since we built the wildcards above into the values.
    list<account> tempClientList = new list <account>([SELECT name, ID
                                                   FROM account
                                                   WHERE name LIKE:tempNameList]);

    //Now go through WrapComplaintList and add the Account OBJ
    if(tempClientList.size() >0){
        for (wrapComplaint eachWrap:wrapComplaintList){
            for(account eachAccount:tempClientList){
                if(eachWrap.complaintObj.complainant__c == eachAccount.name)  //HERE IS THE ISSUE
                    eachWrap.ClientOBJ = eachAccount;
                }
            }
        }
```

I commented the line that I have trouble with.  If I use SOQL in a for-loop to comparate each value to a property, I can assign it no problem, but I can't do that in a For Loop.  How would I build an If-Statement that can compare values?  Any thoughts here?

Comment: What do you mean by compare values? It seems to be that you are there you only want to know if the complaint name is "Contained" in the account name. Here is the issue - if Complaint A value is "John" and Complain B value is "Smith" then they would both map to account with name value "John Smith". Can you more clearly state what you are trying to accomplish - at a higher more abstract level.

Comment: Sure.  Basically I get an account string from an external source, which may or may not exactly match the SF Account Name string.  I can't get an actual ID, so I have to compare the two values to see if there's a match.  'contains' is too simple, but someone pointed me to the regEx function, so that seems to be what I need actually.

Comment: Regular Expressions can definitely work but you are still going to have to determine a "matching" threshold - the level of comparison that a match is deemed to be true.

Comment: Yeah... that's my issue as well.  I'm trying to find a tutorial on RegEx.  I just need to it work exactly like the soql "LIKE" function does.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Well when you put the "%" on both sides of a word the LIKE acts EXACTLY like the string "Contains" function. If you get Account name "ACME" from your external source and have an "ACME Studios" and "ACME LTD" you will have to have the system make a choice. When I am dealing with scenarios such as these I try to not make the decision myself. I will typically add them to a bucket "NO EXACT ACCOUNT FOUND" account that then alerts someone to go and make an informed decision about where the account needs to go. The above scenario will never match to the others no matter what regex function you use.

Comment: Ah I see!  Thanks for much for clearing it up - I didn't know that %this% was contains.  Your method is the best way - I'll just put it in a bucket for no exact match, send a notification, and an admin can do it.  THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RC82: if you have a way to selectively sort on Account, here is an alternate approach. You will have to add in your wrapper classes, etc but the pattern I've outlined will help you simplify things:

```
//inbound complaint__c records
Map<String,complaint__c> cMap = new Map<String,complaint__c>();
for(complaint__c tmp : [SELECT ID, Name, Complainant__c FROM complaint__c]) {
    cMap.put(tmp.Complainant__c, tmp);
}

//placeholder for matched Accounts
Map<String,Account> aMap = new Map<String,Account>();

//find a way to make this query selective... e.g. WHERE condition1, etc
for(List<Account> aList : [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account]) {
    for(String s : cMap.keySet()) {
        for(Account a: aList) {
            if(s.contains(a.Name))
                //load up matched accounts
                aMap.put(a.Name,a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I made a version of this on a trigger on record insert, so I don't have to worry about matching in my search class.  Thanks!